# Where to define functors used by many derived classes?

Tags: c++

A common scenario in my code is that I got a **functor** that is used by many classes in a hierachy.

To make it accessible by all classes and stay DRY, I usually define it as a protected inner struct of my base class like that:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    struct CommonFunctor
    {
        bool operator()()
        {
            return true;
        }
    };
};

class DerivedA : public Base
{
    void FooA()
    {
        bool test = CommonFunctor()();
    }
};

class DerivedB : public Base
{
    void FooB()
    {
        bool test = CommonFunctor()();
    }
};
```

I don't like that solution because it clutters my base class with many small functors, that are internal only and even if they are not accessible to the public, they decrease readability of my base class.

**Do you know any other solutions for this scenario?**

Comment: What's the problem with them being defined in the same namespace as the classes they work with?

Comment: Why not just declare the functor `operator()()` in the class definition and define the functor elsewhere?

Comment: @hmjd: That's what I did. I only merged definition and declaration for my code example. Still a lot of clutter in my base class header file...

Comment: @GeneBushuyev: You are right: I could just declare all those functors inside my namespace in a separate header file like `CommonFunctors.h` and include it in all my derived classes. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement your functors in new files (`BaseClassFunctors.cpp` + `BaseClassFunctors.h`). Put them inside your namespace with an optional subnamespaces (e.g. namespace main.internal).

Now you include the header file in any derived classes you want, without cluttering the base class header.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I (and, apparently, everyone else) hate multiple inheritance, it would come in handy here.

Just create a second class that contains all your functors and in your child classes derived from `Base`, inherit both `Base` and this new class.

Comment: I never thought to use multiple inheritance for that. Thanks for a new insight.

Comment: I hope it answers your question. Another solution would be to make your functor class derive from `Base`, then derive `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` from the functor class alone. Less clean, more hacky.

Comment: This is certainly one answer to my question. I wonder if there are any other solutions out there....

Comment: Derivation means *is-a* relationship, nothing to do with functors.

Comment: @Gene doesn't matter what derivation *means* so much as how it works and what it lets you do. If it makes you feel better, call the class `ConsumerOfManyFunctors` and then `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` and can derive from it, if that makes you feel better knowing you can say `DerivedA` *is-a* `ConsumerOfManyFunctors`.

Comment: @Mahmoud Al-Qudsi - since when basic design principles became a matter of feeling better? I'm saying the design is wrong, it's not a matter of feelings. You need to read what inheritance actually means.

Comment: @Gene Obviously I know what derivation *means*. It just has no bearing on the matter at hand. This isn't UML, this is the real world. I never said this is what derivation means in the dictionary of computer science, I just posted a somewhat elegant solution *that works exactly as the OP needs it to*.

Answer (score 0):

You can just implement the functor elsewhere and still keep it as a member of the Base:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    struct CommonFunctor;
};   

struct Base::CommonFunctor
{
    bool operator()()
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```